# Excel : dynamic column reference for SUMIFS

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been looking on the internet for a solution for my problem, but I can't find any.
Basically I'm looking for a way to use a SUMIFS and dynamically change the sum area which should match with the month.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Here you can see that C2:C4 is a fixed range. I'd liked the columns to change based on the month a user would typed in C8.

Example: for 01/02/2019 in C8, the formula would become `=SUMIFS(C2:C4;**D2:D4**;B9)`

I know I'd have to use an INDEX, MATCH function but it's a pain to figure it how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this in B10 and copy down.

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$4,A10,INDEX($B$2:$D$4,,MATCH($B$9,$B$1:$D$1,0)))
```

The MATCH finds the position of the date in the top range (in this case 1)

The INDEX returns the relevant column (i.e. B2:B4)

You can probably figure out the rest ...

[image]

Comment: Great response ! Thank you so much for this. Just to understand, why does =INDEX($B$2:$D$4,,MATCH($B$9,$B$1:$D$1,0)) alone gives me a #!VALUE error ? Otherwise it's working within the SUMIF function but i'd like to understand this behavior!

Comment: My pleasure. The INDEX bit alone returns a range, in this case B2:B4, so it cannot return a result into the cell. It is only when you wrap it in a SUM (or similar formula) that it can convert this to value. A range on its own is meaningless. Make sense?

Comment: Ok thanks that was my hypothesis. Another qurestion : i've seen if I declare the range as a table by respectfully declaring what worked previously but as a table it doesn't work anymore. I can't fixed this. Why is this ?

Comment: @polo31 The result of that is an array, an array cannot fit in a single cell, hence the error. You can use Formula > Evaluate formula to see what that array looks like before turning into an error.

Comment: To add to Jerry's point if you enter that formula, highlight 3 cells and use ctrl shift and enter for an array formula you will get the 3 values returned 2,1,2. Not sure what you mean by your second question - could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go for an array formula (after typing the formula, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> -- you can know it works when you see braces `{}` around the formula in the formula bar) with `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$D$4*($A$2:$A$4=A9)*($B$1:$D$1=B8))
```

[image]

It basically means sum the range B2:D4 where A2:A4 = A9 and where B1:D1 = B8.

Comment: Oops yes it does

Comment: Thanks for the effort to respond Jerry! i found something better but i'll keep this in mind.